# Get the first document using $in with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

how can get the first element using in in mongo ?
if i've a list like `['car', 'house', 'cat', dog']`, and a collection which contains many documents these element, i'd like to find the first document which contain `cat`, and first which contains `dog` etc.

I've tried to use `limit()` but in fact it gives me only one document, which can be either `car`, or `dog` or `cat` etc.

is there a way to combine a limit with $in ?

Thanks

EDIT: 
example of data i've:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51d53ace9e674607e837d62d"
    },
    "sensors": [{
        "name": "os-hostname",
        "value": "yahourt"
    }, {
        "name": "os-domain-name",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "os-platform",
        "value": "Win32NT"
    }, {
        "name": "os-fullname",
        "value": "Microsoft Windows XP Professional"
    }, {
        "name": "os-version",
        "value": "5.1.2600.131072"
    }],
    "type": "os",
    "serial": "2_os_os-hostname_yahourt"
} {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51d53ace9e674607e837d62e"
    },
    "sensors": [{
        "name": "cpu-id",
        "value": "_Total"
    }, {
        "name": "cpu-usage",
        "value": 37.2257042
    }],
    "type": "cpu",
    "serial": "2_cpu_cpu-id_total"
} {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51d53ace9e674607e837d62f"
    },
    "sensors": [{
        "name": "cpu-id",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "cpu-usage",
        "value": 48.90282
    }],
    "type": "cpu",
    "serial": "2_cpu_cpu-id_0"
} {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51d53ace9e674607e837d630"
    },
    "sensors": [{
        "name": "cpu-id",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "cpu-usage",
        "value": 25.54859
    }],
    "type": "cpu",
    "serial": "2_cpu_cpu-id_1"
} {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51d53ace9e674607e837d631"
    },
    "sensors": [{
        "name": "volume-name",
        "value": "C:"
    }, {
        "name": "volume-label",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "volume-total-size",
        "value": "52427898880"
    }, {
        "name": "volume-total-free-space",
        "value": "20305170432"
    }, {
        "name": "volume-percent-free-space",
        "value": "38"
    }, {
        "name": "volume-reads-per-second",
        "value": 0.0
    }, {
        "name": "volume-writes-per-second",
        "value": 9.324152
    }, {
        "name": "volume-read-bytes-per-second",
        "value": 0.0
    }, {
        "name": "volume-write-bytes-per-second",
        "value": 194141.6
    }, {
        "name": "volume-queue-length",
        "value": 0.0
    }],
    "type": "disk",
    "serial": "2_disk_volume-name_c"
}
```

Comment: What would determine the "first" of each category? Is there an order or something?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a limit to $in but you could cheat by using the aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{serial:{$in:[list_of_serials]}}},
    {$sort:{_id:-1}},
    {$group:{_id:'$serial',type:{$first:'$type'},sensors:{$first:'$sensors'},id:{$first:'$_id'}}}
]);
```

Would get a list of all first found of each type.

#### Edit

The update will get the last inserted according to the `_id`.

Comment: it's not valid :( I've attacahed an example i've in my collection. imagine i've these data each minute stored in my collection. How can i get the last Insert ? Serial field is the key.

Comment: @gorjuce you can sort on `_id`, that will be at least mostly accurate, to about 90% in your case I think

Comment: @gorjuce What do you mean "Serial field is the key"? Do you mean you just need it back?

Comment: nope. i mean i need the last documents where serial is in [mySerialList]. all document field need to be returned.
i.e: the last document where serial is xxxx, the last document where serial is xxx2, etc. where xxx is in [mySerialList]. You know what i mean ?

Comment: @gorjuce I think You wanna query by a $in of serials but you wanna get the last inserted of each type?

Comment: each minute, i receive datas. A data is composed of a sensors list, a type and a serial. Datas are stored as shown in the first post (3 documents shown). I'd like to get the last docmuments inserted for a given serial list.

Comment: @gorjuce Then what is stopping: `db.collection.find({serials:{$in:[]}}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)` That will get the last inserted for that serial list

Comment: wrong cause the limit is applied on all results and not on $in.

Comment: maybea easier to understand : I have a list of serial, so I look for the last inserted document for each of the serial list

Comment: @gorjuce My aggregation should do exactly that in its updated form, it should give a list of last inserted docs per serial with the serial as the _id and the _id as id and all the other fields as they are now

Comment: i've tried but i don't know why i've a result lengt of 46 while i've 281 serials in my list.